# Timer app to work when the screen is off ios

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have a timer app that that is supposed to run for hours and play sounds at certain intervals. How can I make this work when the screen is off (to save battery) or another app like ibooks is open? Currently, I run my timer function in the ViewDidLoad. Maybe that's the problem. What would be the correct approach here?

Comment: scheduling local notifications maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schedule a user notification request using [`UNNotificationRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest). Provide a `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` or `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` object as the trigger, depending if your need.

If you need iOS 9 and below support, there is an analogous `UILocalNotification` API that is deprecated in iOS 10, but can be used in case backward compatibility is needed.

Note, that once the notification fires, it is client-side only, and your app will not wake up to perform tasks. Only if the user chooses to activate the notification, will your app get a running context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is the timer freezes when the app goes in the background or the phone goes to sleep mode. My app requires that it doesn't. I checked out a number of sports timers and running apps, and they do not freeze when other apps are run simultaneously.

Comment: Apps go to sleep when in background. However you can save the time of going to sleep, and then restart your timer by calculating how much time has passed between now and the time your app went to sleep. You can use `NSDate`, or if you require more precision, you can use mach time.

Comment: Have you researched the audio background mode capability?

Comment: Background audio will not help. Apple no longer allows applications that play "silence" in the background just to get execution time, nor is that good idea for the users who do not want their battery to drain. A reminder: iOS now displays what apps use the most battery, and users remove applications that are abusing the battery.

Comment: I think that could work, but in this case what can be done about the sound signals that are attached to the running timer? Is there way to let the app legally run in the background if it is absolutely needed?

Comment: No. Only voip and location apps get to run in the background with full execution privileges, and your apps is neither. You need to figure out your design within the possibilities of the system.

Comment: Thank you. Now that I understand the possibilities, I will try to figure it out

Comment: Also read this guide by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html